# 404 not found on method POST on form

Tags: html, forms

I got this simple form on a page. I run this on localhost but when I run the form it shall redirect to http://localhost:63342/welcome.html

but instead I get the 404 not found message.

When I mark the url in the browser and hit return the correct page shows. But the redirect doesnt work when using method="POST" to localhost

Any idea how to solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" action="welcome.html">
        <input type="text" id="test" name="test"/>
        <input type="submit" value="test"/>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does your server-side code look like? It's possible that your server isn't mapping the POST action. If you put the url in the browser, that uses the GET action.

Comment: I dont know really what the server side code look like (how do I find that). 

I just load my form to the browser using Webstorm.

Comment: That depends on your environment and what language you are using. Are you using php?

Comment: No i dont use php. Could it be something as simple as a setting in Webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the GET method instead of the POST method.

Have a look here for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Well. the thing is im making a login page. With the GET everything is shown in the url

Comment: Then you need some PHP in your welcome.html (then welcome.php) file to catch the POST data.

Comment: Is it possibly only a problem when i run in Localhost? Im using Webstorm to preview my site

Comment: That depends if Webstorm also has a PHP module installed/active. I'm guessing Webstorm is something similair than XAMP/LAMP/WAMP/MAMP